# Square Root of the Product of Convergent Series Converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I go about proving that Square Root of the Product of Convergent Series Converges, where both are greater than 0. So $\sum \sqrt{x_n y_n}$, where $\sum x_n$ and $\sum y_n$ converge, and each $x_n$ and $y_n$ are greater than 0

Comment: Do you know the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: I do not. Never heard of it.

Comment: $0\le(a-b)^2$.${}$

Comment: I am not sure what the hint $0≤(a−b)^2$ means

Comment: So, $0\le a^2+b^2-2ab\Rightarrow 2ab\le a^2+b^2$. Use $a=\sqrt {x_n}$, $b=\sqrt {y_n}$ and the Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of going about this is to apply the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).  Looking at the partial sums $\displaystyle s_k = \sum_{j=1}^k \sqrt{x_jy_j}$, we have the following:

$$s_k^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^k x_j \cdot \sum_{j=1}^k y_j$$

The partial sums $x_k$ and $y_k$ are bounded above by $\displaystyle L = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ and $\displaystyle M = \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$ respectively, since we know those series converge.  Therefore, from the above, we get:

$$s_k^2 \leq L \cdot M$$

That is to say, $s_k \leq \sqrt{L \cdot M}$.

And so the sequence of partial sums $s_k$ is increasing and bounded above, so what can we conclude?

---

As Jimmy mentioned in the comments, the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) will get you there a lot faster.  The inequality says that the geometric mean of a set of numbers is dominated by the arithmetic mean of that set.  Applied to this specific case, we have, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\sqrt{x_ky_k} \leq \frac{x_k + y_k}{2}$$

And so we have a nice comparison test:

$$\sum \sqrt{x_ky_k} \leq \frac{1}{2}\sum \left( x_k + y_k \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum x_k + \sum y_k \right)$$